# Markov Chain: Balance equations for a failing system

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

> Customers arrive in a FIFO queue with rate $\lambda$ and are serviced with mean time $\dfrac1\mu$. The system occasionally fails with time distribution between failures with mean $\dfrac1\gamma$. When the system fails, all customers are dropped.

The Markov chain that I came up with is below. Is it correct?

[image]

Assuming the Markov chain above is correct, how can we write the balance equations? Below is what I have:
$$
\begin{align*}
\lambda P_0 &= \mu P_1 + \gamma(P_1 + P_2 + \cdots + P_n + \cdots) = \mu P_1 + \gamma(1 - P_0)\\
\implies P_1 &= \frac{\lambda + \gamma}\mu P_0 - \frac\gamma\mu
\end{align*}
$$
After this, the balance equations start to become very convoluted
$$
\begin{align*}
\lambda P_1 &= \mu P_2 + \gamma(P_2 + P_3 + \cdots + P_n + \cdots) = \mu P_2 + \gamma(1 - P_0 - P_1) \\
\implies P_2 &= \left(\frac{\lambda(\lambda + \gamma)}{\mu^2} + \frac\gamma\mu + \frac{\gamma(\lambda + \gamma)}{\mu^2}\right)P_0 - \frac{\lambda\gamma}{\mu} - \frac\gamma\mu-\frac{\gamma^2}{\mu^2}
\end{align*}
$$
You can imagine that finding $P_3 \cdots$ would be a nightmare. I cannot figure out a closed form expression for $P_n$. The most I can come up with is
$$
P_n = \frac{\lambda P_{n-1} - \gamma\left(1 - \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}P_i\right)}{\mu}
$$
How would I find $P_n$? I am given a hint to guess an expression of the form $P_k = (1 - \beta)\beta^k$ where $P_k$ represents the steady-state probability of finding $k$ customers in the system. Any tips?

Comment: The above can only be viewed as a CTMC if the associated service times are independent and exponentially distributed, and the failure times are independent and exopnentially distributed.  With these exponential assumptions, a quick scan of your balance equations looks good.  I imagine that good things happen when you plug $P_i = (1-\beta)\beta^i$ into your equations, we get for $n \geq 1$: $$(1-\beta)\beta^n = \frac{\lambda (1-\beta)\beta^{n-1} - \gamma(1-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (1-\beta)\beta^i)}{\mu}$$

Comment: @Michael Yes, all random variables are independent and exponentially distributed. The problem I am facing is in finding an expression for $P_n$ that is not dependent on any other steady-state probabilities (like we have $P_n = (1 - \rho)\rho^n$ for M/M/1). How do I apply the normalization condition, i.e. $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty P_n = 1$, to the expression for $P_n$ that I have?

Comment: If $P_i = (1-\beta)\beta^i$ (for $0<\beta < 1$ and $i \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$) then indeed $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P_i=1$ already.  It remains only to find a $\beta$ value that is consistent with your balance equations.

Comment: @an4s It seems that the serial downvoter fine-tuned its voting pattern to circumvent automatic reversal. In light of this, you could ask for moderators' investigation and intervention, or send an email to the SE company if it gets persistent. Btw, you could always off-set these behaviors by writing new answers. After all, it's been quite so long since your last answer :)

Comment: @an4s Another note: if there're any accounts suspected of downvoting your answers, you could delete these answers for a while and check if these accounts' reputation get +1 or +2.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco thanks for the input. I have asked in one of the chatrooms. I hope someone can help. Somebody is holding a grudge, it seems :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the exponential assumptions from my above comments, your work looks good.  Good things indeed seem to happen when substituting $P_i = (1-\beta)\beta^i$ into your balance equations. If everything works properly, while you might find multiple $\beta$ that work for your equations, you should be able to find one and only one value of $\beta$ that satisfies $0<\beta < 1$ (else, there would be two distinct probability vector solutions to the balance equations, which is impossible for irreducible CTMCs).

Comment: I am told that $\lambda=\mu=\gamma=1$, which simplifies the equation to $$\begin{align*}(1 - \beta)\beta^n &= (1 - \beta)\beta^{n - 1} - 1 + \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}(1 - \beta)\beta^i \\
(1 - \beta)\beta^n &= (1 - \beta)\beta^{n - 1} - 1 + (1 - \beta)\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}\beta^i\end{align*}$$
The sum in the expression above is a geometric progression. So,
$$\begin{align*}(1 - \beta)\beta^n &= (1 - \beta)\beta^{n - 1} - 1 + (1 - \beta)\frac{1 - \beta^n}{1 - \beta}\\
(1 - \beta)\beta^n &= \beta^{n - 1} - \beta^n - \beta^n \\
(1 - \beta) &= \frac1\beta - 2\\\beta^2 - 3\beta + 1 &= 0\end{align*}$$

Comment: Solving this equation gives me $\beta = 2.618, 0.382$. Since $0 < \beta < 1$, $\beta = 0.382$.
Does this look good?

Comment: Yes, that looks good.  These are interesting problems, where do they come from?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The questions are from my communication networks class.